# The number of Hamiltonian paths in a tournament is always odd?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

A tournament is defined as an orientation of a complete graph. Prove or disprove the following statement:

> In a tournament, there are exactly an odd number of Hamiltonian paths.

In all cases I’ve tried, the statement seems true, so I guess it’s always true. But to prove it, I really got confused. Two ideas have come up but get nowhere. Please help.

1. Induction on number of vertices;
2. Show that changing the direction of one edge won’t change the parity.

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/q/232751